# HANA: Commit to log tables but not transactional tables

Tags: sql, transactions, hana

I have a procedure that looks something like this:

```
CALL CreateSalesOrder(iv_customer => lv_customerId);
CALL LogMessage('Created sales order');
CALL CreateSalesOrderDetail(iv_customer => lv_customerId, iv_product => lv_productId);
CALL LogMessage('Created sales order detail');
```

I would like the log messages to be written to the table regardless of whether or not the transaction succeeds. I need the ability to look through log messages in the event of a failure, and my log messages contain details about the state of the data that I was manipulating. Having the data available would help troubleshoot issues.

Is there any way to commit data to one table while maintaining safe transactions for the rest of my tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer. The concept is called an **autonomous transaction**, using the same name as found in Oracle.

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2014/12/01/new-sqlscript-features-in-sap-hana-10-sps9

```
BEGIN AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION
   INSERT INTO LogTable () VALUES ();
   COMMIT;
   RESIGNAL;
END;
```

This feature is available as of SPS09.